# How to calculate unit price and quantity changes in java script/ j-query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a small issue calculating price from Quantity in jQuery. Those are the input boxes I have.

```
<html>
   Quantity: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="txt" value="1" />
   Unit Price: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="item_price" id="item_price" class="txt" value="" />
   Amount: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="total_price" id="total_price" class="txt" value="" />
</html>
```

Here I will show my jQuery code.Quantity ; price and Amount value also changes.jQuery Code, but unable to find the problem?

```
<script>
$('#quantity').click(function () {
        var number = $(this).val();
           var o_val = $("#unit_pricea").val();
           var op_val = number * o_val;
          $("#amounta").val(op_val);
          console.log(op_val);
        });
</script>
```

Here I will share my screen shots.

1. First image whenever I enter unit price amount filed not fill:

[image: First image whenever i enter unit price amount filed not fill]

2. Second image unit price can I change previous value of amount not change:

[image: Second image unit price can i change previous value of amount not change]

3. Quantity will be change amount not changed:

[image: Quantity will be change amount not changed]

Comment: Welcome @ Stack Overflow - Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where is your question? please post your code here

Comment: My Code is in jsfiddle.net once please once check the link

Comment: You have to put your code in your question, and if you want post your jsfiddle link. Please read @KoenHollander comment. So where is your question? what error/problem do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#unit_pricea').change(function () {
             var number = $(this).val();
                var o_val = $("#quantity").val();
                var op_val = number * o_val;
               $("#amounta").val(op_val);
```

Change look like this

Answer (score 2):

Change your script as below.

```
 $("#quantity").change(function(e){
        var number = $(this).val();
        var o_val = $(this).next().val();
        var op_val = number * o_val;
        $("#amounta").val(op_val);
    });
```